# SQL Java JDBC AssertionError

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, junit

I'm running JUnit tests on my code and I'm getting an AssertionError report on my method retrieveByCustomerID. I debugged and realised it's not executing the while loop for some reason. I will post the method and the JUnit test. The asserting is because the result set should contain at least 1 value but since the while loop isn't executing, it is an empty array

My SQL statement is:

```
final static String selectByCustomerID = 
"SELECT id, product_id, customer_id, purchase_date, purchase_amount FROM purchase WHERE customer_id = ?;";

public List<Purchase> retrieveForCustomerID(Connection connection, Long customerID) throws SQLException, DAOException {

        if (customerID == null) 
        {
            throw new DAOException("Trying to retrieve Purchase with NULL customer id");
        }

        List<Purchase> result = new ArrayList<>();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try 
        {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(selectByCustomerID);
            ps.setLong(1, customerID);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) 
            {
                Purchase purch = new Purchase();
                purch.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
                purch.setProductID(rs.getLong("product_id"));
                purch.setCustomerID(rs.getLong("customer_id"));
                purch.setPurchaseDate(rs.getDate("purchase_date"));
                purch.setPurchaseAmount(rs.getDouble("purchase_amount"));
                result.add(purch);
            }

            System.out.println(result + "RESULTS \n");
            return result;
        }
        finally 
        {
        }
    }

public void testRetrieveForCustID() throws Exception
    {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceManager.getDataSource();
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        PurchaseDAO pdao = new PurchaseDaoImpl();

        List<Purchase> purchases = pdao.retrieveForCustomerID(connection, customerID);
        assertTrue(purchases.size() >= 1);

        connection.close();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the correct database? In addition, the statement should be prepared once in the constructor of the class. Why is customerID a `Long` insted of a simple `long`?

Comment: That's how the interface defined it (not allowed to edit); and yes I'm sure I'm connecting to the correct database

Comment: Check with some sort of database viewer if the desired data set is really present.

Comment: Which DBMS and JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: If your sql query is not returning any result then I guess this is the correct behavior. Have you tried executing this query directly on database?

Comment: Please check your database there must be some issue like which `customerId` you provided is not in `Database`. @user3512367